# Computing directional derivative of scalar field $F$ along a straight line

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, tensors

In Pavel Grinfeld's *Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces*, the directional derivative is defined as below:

> A directional derivative measures the rate of change of a scalar field $F$ along a straing line. Let a straight ray $\ell$ emanate from the point $P$. Suppose that $P^*$ is a nearby point on $\ell$ and let $P^*$ approach $P$ in the sense that the distance $PP^*$ approaches zero. Then the directional derivative $\frac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm d\ell}$ at the point $P$ is defined as the limit
> $$\frac{\mathrm dF(P)}{\mathrm d\ell}=\lim_{P^*\to P}\frac{F(P^*)-F(P)}{PP^*}$$

---

Several exercises follow, which I've started working through but I'm unsure whether what I'm doing is correct.

> Evaluate $\frac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm d\ell}$ for $F(P)=$ "Distance from point $P$ to point $A$" in a direction perpendicular to $AP$.

I made a sketch of the situation:

[image]

By definition of $F(P)$, $F(P^*)$ is the length of the line segment $AP^*$ and $F(P)$ is the length of $AP$. So I think we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dF(P)}{\mathrm d\ell}&=\lim_{P^*\to P}\frac{AP^*-AP}{PP^*}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{P^*\to P}\frac{AP^*-AP}{\sqrt{(AP^*)^2-(AP)^2}}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{P^*\to P}\sqrt{\frac{AP^*-AP}{AP^*+AP}}=0
\end{align}$$

because $AP^*\to AP$ as $P^*\to P$.

---

The next exercise is slightly more complicated:

> Evaluate $\frac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm d\ell}$ for $F(P)=$"$1$/(Distance from point $P$ to point $A$)" in the direction from $P$ to $A$.

The sketch is the same as the previous one, but this time it sounds like $A$ lies on $\ell$ somewhere between the point $P$ and the tip of the ray.

[image]

Let $a$ be the distance $AP^*$. Then $AP$ has length $ba$ for some $0<b<1$, and $PP^*$ has length $(1-b)a$. So I think we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dF(P)}{\mathrm d\ell}&=\lim_{P^*\to P}\frac{\frac1{AP^*}-\frac1{AP}}{PP^*}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{b\to1}\frac{\frac1a-\frac1{ba}}{(1-b)a}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{b\to1}-\frac1{ba^2}=-\frac1{(AP)^2}
\end{align}$$

---

**Edit:**

> Evaluate $\frac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm d\ell}$ for $F(P)=$ "Angle between $OA$ and $OP$," where $O$ and $A$ are two given points, in the direction from $P$ to $A$.

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dF(P)}{\mathrm d\ell}&=\lim_{P^*\to P}\frac{\theta^*-\theta}{PP^*}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{\theta^*\to\theta}\frac{\theta^*-\theta}{\sqrt{(OP^*)^2+(OP)^2-2(OP^*)(OP)\cos(\theta^*-\theta)}}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{\theta^*\to\theta}\frac{\theta^*-\theta}{\sqrt{a^2b^2+a^2-2a^2b\cos(\theta^*-\theta)}}=0&(\text{where }a=OP,b>1)
\end{align}$$

**Are the reasoning and solution correct?** The first two solutions I've arrived at seem consistent with what I know about basic calculus, but I'm not sure about the last one.